# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in

Tags: memory

I've tried everything I've read on the forum thread related to this error. Changed the config file etc but the problem doesn't go away. We restored backups from a day when the site was working, but again with no result. We turned off all plugins and again no result. The error was just changing its file and so on and on. Please help[image]

Comment: You need to speak to your host about increasing your memory limit.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but also the opiate. the error remains.

Comment: Hello, the problem is fixed. It turns out to be an automatic WordPress update that is not compatible with the theme version. I reverted to an older version until the theme developers configure it to work with the latest version of WordPress.
Thank you for your help though.